# Implement WebDav client with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, webdav

I've been looking for a way to implement WebDAV client (PROPFIND, DELETE, PUT...) with Silverlight but without any luck. Specify any other values than "POST" and "GET" to HttpWebRequest.Method will just causes an exception in Silverlight.

Is there any other way to do it without using XMLHTTPRequest?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are third-party components an option?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't think there are many options left without using XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: As one of the options I can offer WebDAVBlackbox of our SecureBlackbox ( http://www.eldos.com/SecureBlackbox/desc-webdav.php ). We have Silverlight components. Note that they are subject to restrictions imposed by Microsoft on Socket class connectivity unless you have a trusted application. If you have a trusted one, - no problems, no limitations.